# I made a status command but it's not working

Tags: python-3.x

I made this code:

```py
@client.command()
async def status(ctx):
       em = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Status',
        color = 0x900ff,
        description = "",
        timestamp = ctx.message.created_at

    )
    em.add_field(name = "Online?", value = "Yes", inline=False)
    em.add_field(name = "Ping?", value = f"{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms", inline=False)
    em.set_author(name = "Brobotel V2 is Bacc", url ="", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/mc9Gcdp.jpg")
    em.set_footer(text = f'Invoked by: @{ctx.author}!')

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

But it's giving me an error:

[image: error]

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the indentation is wrong on the line `em = discord.Embed(`. It should be 4 space. Further more please do not use image/links for reporting error.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard thanks, I just started coding again after 1 month and made this account about 15 mins ago just to resolve it (sorry about photo). Also I think I'm blind because I didn't have seen that space!

Answer (score 0):

Your `em = discord.Embed(` should be indented like in below example

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client =  commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
@client.command()
async def status(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Status',
        color = 0x900ff,
        description = "",
        timestamp = ctx.message.created_at

    )
    em.add_field(name = "Online?", value = "Yes", inline=False)
    em.add_field(name = "Ping?", value = f"{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms", inline=False)
    em.set_author(name = "Brobotel V2 is Bacc", url ="", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/mc9Gcdp.jpg")
    em.set_footer(text = f'Invoked by: @{ctx.author}!')

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```